# POST Code being incorrectly formated?

Tags: php, post, curl

I have a PHP script which executes a POST request with the following variable:
`p=%2FL9yGFPv9nEbsH1oYfh3R9q2wiVawsw72UlGnRcObmm80F3EDjQ0aU4EMWcbHybb`

However, my server gets
`p=/L9yGFPv9nEbsH1oYfh3R9q2wiVawsw72UlGnRcObmm80F3EDjQ0aU4EMWcbHybb`

It is a Curl POST request.
What is causing this and how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: %2F is the rul encoding of /

Comment: @Dagon And how to revert the string, so that I get obtain the variable sent?

Comment: http://us3.php.net/urldecode

Comment: show the code. where the heck would `gets` come from?

Comment: echo urldecode('/L9yGFPv9nEbsH1oYfh3R9q2wiVawsw72UlGnRcObmm80F3EDjQ0aU4EMWcbHybb'); - returns the same string ('/L9yGFPv9nEbsH1oYfh3R9q2wiVawsw72UlGnRcObmm80F3EDjQ0aU4EMWcbHybb')

Comment: you use use `urlencode` because you're encoding into url format, not decoding from it

Comment: Thank you @Lashane you saved me. I was using urldecode after catching the code and I wasn't supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to show up correctly, when you get the string on the page, just use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode):

```
$_GET['p'] = urlencode($_GET['p']);
```

This will convert anything that was converted because there was a `%` in front of it for the query string.

Comment: Thank you, that's it. I was using urldecode right after getting it, and I wasn't supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

`urlencode($_POST['the-value']);` will undo any decoding that has been done.

For example...

```
echo urlencode('/L9yGFPv9nEbsH1oYfh3R9q2wiVawsw72UlGnRcObmm80F3EDjQ0aU4EMWcbHybb');
```

will produce...

```
%2FL9yGFPv9nEbsH1oYfh3R9q2wiVawsw72UlGnRcObmm80F3EDjQ0aU4EMWcbHybb
```